# Prove inequality $\frac{x^3}y+\frac{y^3}z+\frac{z^3}x+\frac{x^3}z+\frac{z^3}y+\frac{y^3}x\ge\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+1}2$

Tags: inequality

> Let $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$. Prove that
> $$\frac{x^3}y+\frac{y^3}z+\frac{z^3}x+\frac{x^3}z+\frac{z^3}y+\frac{y^3}x\ge\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+1}2$$

#### My work so far:

I use [Titu's Lemma:](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/)

$$\frac{x^3}y+\frac{y^3}z+\frac{z^3}x+\frac{x^3}z+\frac{z^3}y+\frac{y^3}x=$$
$$=\frac{x^4}{xy}+\frac{y^4}{yz}+\frac{z^4}{zx}+\frac{x^2}{\frac zx}+\frac{z^2}{\frac yz}+\frac{y^2}{\frac xy}\ge$$
$$\ge\frac{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2+x+y+z\right)^2}{xy+yz+zx+ \frac zx+\frac yz+\frac xy}=\frac{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2+1\right)^2}{xy+yz+zx+ \frac zx+\frac yz+\frac xy}$$

*I need help here.*

Comment: Could you use Muirhead? The left handside is a symmetric polynomial in $x,y,z$. On the right side you could eliminate the constraint and have a homogeneous expression by replacing $1=(x+y+z)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \geq y \geq z$. Using the rearrangements inequality we have
$$ \frac{x^3}{y}+\frac{y^3}{z}+\frac{z^3}{x} \geq x^3 \cdot \frac{1}{x}+...+z^3 \cdot \frac{1}{z} =x^2+y^2+z^2 $$
since $x^3,y^3,z^3$ and $1/x,1/y,1/z$ have opposite ordering. The same thing applies to 
$$ \frac{x^3}{z}+\frac{z^3}{y}+\frac{y^3}{x} \geq x^2+y^2+z^2$$
Thus the left hand side is greater than $2(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. This is immediately greater than the RHS by noting that $1=(x+y+z)^2$.

---

You could use "Titu's Lemma" if you like, just like in your try, but split in half:
$$ \frac{x^3}{y}+\frac{y^3}{z}+\frac{z^3}{x} \geq \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{xy+yz+zx} \geq \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = x^2+y^2+z^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\frac{x^3}y+\frac{y^3}z+\frac{z^3}x+\frac{x^3}z+\frac{z^3}y+\frac{y^3}x=\frac{x^4+y^4}{xy}+\frac{y^4+z^4}{yz}+\frac{z^4+x^4}{zx},$$
$$S=\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2}{xy}+\frac{(y^2+z^2)^2-2y^2z^2}{yz}+\frac{(z^2+x^2)^2-2z^2x^2}{zx}.$$
Since $(a^2+b^2)^2=(a^2+b^2)(a^2+b^2)\geq 2ab(a^2+b^2)$ by AM-GM, we have
$$S\geq 4(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+yz+zx),$$
$$S\geq\frac{7}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+yz+zx)+\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}.$$

Since $$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq 2(xy+yz+zx)$$ holds (because it is equivalent with $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2$),

we have
$$S\geq\frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)+\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}.$$
Also, $$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$ by quadratic-arithmetic inequality. 
Therefore,
$$S\geq\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)^2+\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}$$
$$S\geq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+1}{2}.$$